# How to produce a hash (#) in a data URI in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, data-uri

I have an SVG that includes a hash (#). Now, I want to use the SVG in an img data URI. However, Firefox will not show the image.

Here is a minimal example. The first img works fine while the second does not.

```html
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100px" width="100px">
      <text x="50" y="50">X</text>
    </svg>' alt="" />
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100px" width="100px">
      <text x="50" y="50">#</text>
    </svg>' alt="" />
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdwmKZ

Works fine in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Awesome: the answer is 23, or to be more precise %23.

Comment: Note that Firefox has spec-compliant behaviour, Chrome is switching to this also: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5656049583390720